# Rails 3, where to put method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey have method called voted? that sees if someone voted. Where would I put it so it can be used in both the controller and view? First thought about placing it in the Voting Records model but I can't call current_user there. Then the project helper, but it fails there as well?

```
def voted?(project)
   Project.votes.exists?( :project_id => project.id, :user_id => current_user.id )
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered this?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes # assuming you have this association
  def voted?(project)
    votes.exists?(:project_id => project)
  end
end
```

Now you can use the following anywhere, in controllers (keeping them skinny), in views keeping it neat.

```
current_user.voted?(project)
```

Comment: Great, works just like I wanted it to. Thanks, only 5 days into using rails.

Answer (score 1):

You should put it inside the `User` class. However: You should have it use the `user_id` of the user instance, rather than the `current_user`

Answer (score 0):

put it in the helper for your model..

e.g. ./app/helpers/yourmodel_helper.rb